# \let and \def differentiation in D. Knuth's commentary (plain TeX)

Tags: macros, plain-tex, definition

In the The TeX Book, in apendix B, I read

```
\def\obeyspaces{\catcode`\ =\active}
{\obeyspaces\global\let =\space}
{%
\catcode`\^^M=\active % these lines must end with ‘%’
\gdef\obeylines{\catcode`\^^M=\active \let^^M=\par}%    
\global\let^^M=\par % this is in case ^^M appears in a \write
}
```

> The \obeylines macro says ‘\let^^M=\par’ instead of ‘\def^^M{\par}’ because the
> \let technique allows constructions such as ‘\let\par=\cr \obeylines \halign{...}’
> in which \cr’s need not be given within the alignment.

But I don't get the suggested point in that comment. Could someone help me?

Comment: In most computer languages, every variable is assigned a location in memory.  In others, (like MATLAB) the name can point to any location in memory and frequently changes.  \def assigns a token string to a macro name.  \let assigns the location of a previously defined token string to a name.  The token string will not be changed or deleted until there are no macros linked to it (TeX keeps track).

Comment: @JohnKormylo I always wondered, what happens internally in TeX when you `\let` some macro be equal to a primitive and then delete the original primitive?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For (some) purposes, a primitive `\halign` needs to directly "see" the `&` and `\cr` tokens that end alignment cells. You can see the effect in LaTeX where some packages grabbing cell contents don't work so well in the last column, which ends with `\\`  (which is a macro with `\cr` in its definition) as opposed to other columns that end with `&` directly.

By using `\let` as described, the end result is that at the end of line TeX places an active character with meaning  the `\cr` csname, and not an active character with a meaning that is a macro that expands to `\cr`.

The following example produces two alignments but if you change `\iffalse` to `\iftrue` a third attempt using the suggested definition with `\def` instead of `\let` is used, which fails.

```
\def\test#1{[#1]}

\halign{\hfil\test{#}\cr
aaa\cr
bb\cr
c\cr}

{\let\par\cr\obeylines%
\halign{\hfil\test{#}
aaa
bb
c
}}%


\iffalse % this doesn't work
{%
\catcode`\^^M=\active % these lines must end with ‘%’
\gdef\obeylines{\catcode`\^^M=\active \def^^M{\par}}%    
\global\def^^M{\par}% this is in case ^^M appears in a \write
} 

{\let\par\cr\obeylines%
\halign{\hfil\test{#}
aaa
bb
c
}}%

\fi
\bye
```

Comment: I've certainly hit the \\ problem a few times (in `tabular`, if I recall), but I don't recall the circumstances (some macro manipulating cell contents).  Thanks for the elucidation.

Comment: If I got, \halign scans its content looking for tips (\cr and &) to define and check its structure. Macros has, in some way, the address of the content that defines it. Using \let to define a macro, the new one has a copy of this specific address where the binding macro points to. By the way, using \def, a new memory is located. So, when \halign scans its content, he can't deal with such indirect reference, accusing a problem. I know that it's a fairy tale... but sounds someway real. I think I got the point. Thank you!